# How to pass Multiple KeyEvents into a Method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, logic

I am having a array `UNICODE_EXCEPTION` which is passed to the below function.The Array has 2 values.One is the unicode name & the KeyEvent.

Now I want to pass the Keyboard shortcuts to the Method.Every shortcut has 2 or 3 Key Events.So i want the Method to detect the no. of KeyEvents in the Array & React according to it.

**For example:**
If it is has 2 KeyEvents.It must perform with 2 Keypress & release it

```
//the first action
this.application.getRobot().keyPress(UNICODE_EXCEPTION[i][1]);
this.application.getRobot().keyPress(UNICODE_EXCEPTION[i][1]);
//the second action
this.application.getRobot().keyRelease(UNICODE_EXCEPTION[i][2]);
this.application.getRobot().keyRelease(UNICODE_EXCEPTION[i][2]);
```

How Can i Achieve this ???

So Help me in the Right Direction :)

Thanks for your Help ...

**METHOD**

```
private void keyboardUnicodeTrick(KeyboardAction action)
    {
        boolean exception = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < UNICODE_EXCEPTION.length; i++)
        {
            if (action.unicode == UNICODE_EXCEPTION[i][0])
            {
                exception = true;

                this.application.getRobot().keyPress(UNICODE_EXCEPTION[i][1]);
                this.application.getRobot().keyRelease(UNICODE_EXCEPTION[i][1]);

                break;
            }
        }
        if (!exception)
        {
            pressUnicode(this.application.getRobot(), action.unicode);
        }
    }
```

**ARRAY**

```
private static final int[][] UNICODE_EXCEPTION = {
        {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_BACKSPACE, KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE,
        }, {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_PAGEDN, KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN
        }, {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_PAGEUP, KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP
        }, {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_TAB, KeyEvent.VK_TAB
        }, {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_ARROW_DOWN, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN
        }, {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_ARROW_UP, KeyEvent.VK_UP
        }, {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_ARROW_LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT
        }, {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_ARROW_RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT
        }, {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_ESC, KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE
        }, {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_F5, KeyEvent.VK_F5
        }, {
                KeyboardAction.UNICODE_CTRL, KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL
        }
};
```

Comment: is it intended that you use the index `1` four times in your example? I suppose it should be `1` and `2` - i.e. two different actions - right?

Comment: ya .. They are two different actions ...

Comment: ok, then my answer does exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

First, I would not use an array like you did. Seems a `Map` is much better suited for what you do. After all you associate values (in your case 'actions') with a key. Like so:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> unicodeExceptions;
//initialize it, key is a KeyboardAction, value is a list of KeyEvent constants
```

Then you will not need your for loop. And by using `List<Integer>` as value argument you can then call your methods (that is if I fully understood your question). So your method would look something like this:

```
private void keyboardUnicodeTrick(KeyboardAction action) {
    if (unicodeException.containsKey(action)) {
        List<Integer> actions = unicodeExceptions.get(action);
        //first press them
        for (Integer keyEvent: actions) {
            this.application.getRobot().keyPress(keyEvent);
        }
        //edit: then release them
        for (Integer keyEvent: actions) {
            this.application.getRobot().keyRelease(keyEvent);
        }
        return;
    }
    pressUnicode(this.application.getRobot(), action.unicode);
}
```

You don't even need your boolean flag anymore. I hope this helps, Im not sure if I fully understood your question though.

---

Edit: didn't know you are new to maps, I suggest reading up on collections in java. they are really helpful! here is a snippet to initialize the map:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> unicodeExceptions = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
unicodeExceptions.put(KeyboardAction.UNICODE_BACKSPACE,  Arrays.asList(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, KeyEvent.VK_UP, ...)); 
//and so on...
```

Comment: See my Example in the Question. It must perform different actions according to the no. of KeyEvents.

Comment: Yes, and now it does. If you add for example `KeyEvent.VK_DOWN` and `KeyEvent.VK_UP` into the list for key `KeyboardAction.UNICODE_ARROW_UP`, it will call the `keyPress & keyRelease` methods for both of these actions.

Comment: If i give KeyEvent.VK_DOWN and KeyEvent.VK_UP.It must KeyPress down & UP.then Release both the keys.Now your method Keypress down & releases & Keypress up & releases.

Comment: ok, simple: have a for loop where you press them, and one where you release them;